# Turning a list of notes and timings into useful sheet music

Tags: graphics, string-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
songnotes = {"d5", "d5", "e5", "d5", "d5", "c5", "c5", "a4", "a4", "c5"}
(* timing is the amount of time between the start of the notes *)
timing = {1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}
```

And what I want is some sort of visually useful way of me learning how to play the song I just generated. I'm very much an engineer and not a music person (see: this question), so I don't know how to visualize music in written form. The instrument I'm using is the Hapi tone mini drum and only has the following notes:

```
noteletters = {"c4", "d4", "e4", "g4", "a4", "c5", "d5", "e5"}
```

I welcome creative responses here because I'm not sure what the best way for me to learn is.

Comment: You have 10 notes in your song, but 11 entries in your timing list.  Should I think of this as: wait 1/4 d5 wait 1/4 d5 wait 1/4 e5 wait 1/4 ... a4 wait 1/2 c5 wait 1/2?

Comment: Ah! I don't know how the 11th got in there. It should be equal length lists!

Comment: So in theory it's d5 1/4 d5 1/4 ... c5 1/2

Comment: Music types have kind of figured this out already [Music theory](http://www.musictheory.net/lessons/10).  Staffs, clefs, ledger lines, notes, time indications.  It gives one a remarkably accessible language, grammar, and syntax for doing this sort of thing.  Interesting that no one has mentioned it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a couple of options that might get your creative juice flowing:

1) Make a ListPlot

```
songnotes = {"d5", "d5", "e5", "d5", "d5", "c5", "c5", "a4", "a4", "c5"};
timing = {1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2};
noteletters = {"c4", "d4", "e4", "g4", "a4", "c5", "d5", "e5"}
```

Make a substitution rule to help our gathering and sorting. I want each tone to be in a group for coloring purposes.

```
rule = Thread[noteletters -> Range[8]]
notes = GatherBy[
  SortBy[Last]@(Thread[{Most@FoldList[Plus, 0, timing], 
       songnotes}] /. rule), Last]
```

Once grouped, use ListPlot:

```
ListPlot[notes, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 4, 1/4], Thread[{Range[8], noteletters}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 9}}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 AspectRatio -> 1/5, ImageSize -> Large, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 4], Range[8]}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

2) Use SparseArray and then MatrixPlot:

```
elements = 
 Thread[Accumulate[timing] -> songnotes] /. rule /. 
  HoldPattern[a_ -> b_] :> {b, 4 a} -> b
```

set up some color rules:

```
colors = Thread[Range[1, 8] -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[2 ;; 9]]]

MatrixPlot[SparseArray[elements], DataReversed -> True, 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> White}~Join~colors, Mesh -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {All, {1, 16}, All} , 
 FrameTicks -> {Thread[{Range[8], noteletters}], None} ]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. That is so cool. Thanks so much!!

Comment: I'd thought about improving this by using the actual symbols for the notes, but it seems *Mathematica* can only show quarter and eighth notes. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

If you can procure some software for edition:visualisation of MIDI files you can use Mathematica's Export capability:

```
Sound[Apply [SoundNote ,
Transpose[{
        songnotes = {"d5", "d5", "e5", "d5", "d5", "c5", "c5", "a4", "a4",
           "c5"},
        (*timing is the amount of time between the start of the notes*)

          timing = {1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2} }
       ] , {1}] ]

    Export["mySong.mid", %]
```