Music notation in WL/Mathematica
Is there any way to draw a musical staff with clefs, notes, etc. in the Wolfram Language?
E.g., a simple grand staff like this one:

Any links to relevant paclets, ResourceFunctions, etc. would be most welcome.

Not sure if any of these answers are useful to you: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77805/9490

@JasonB. - These solutions look cool, but this is not quite what I am looking for.
I am now attempting a solution via MaTeX.

If typesetting music sheet is your ultimate goal, why don't you use musiXTeX or its syntax sugar, PMX or M-Tx?

The goal is to generate a bunch of Anki flashcards for music theory algorithmically. I learned about musiXTeX just yesterday.
My current idea is to build a Mathematica -> musiXTeX -> Anki pipeline.
But perhaps there is an easier way (?).
